# Use free() for a struct containing array

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

```
typedef struct Rental {
    int nDays;
    float kmsDriven;
    char carLicensePlate[LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH+1];
    char *clientName;
    char chargingCategory;
} Rental;
```

I got the upper struct and i made an array of pointers to these structures this way:

```
Rental* rentArray[nRent];`
```

I try to use free it but `rentArray[0]` still remains not empty . What is wrong?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. 1. `free()` won't clear the variable passed as the argument since it won't accept pointer of variable to clear. 2. If you try to dereference `rentArray[0]` after freeing it, you are wrong. Don't access freed memory!

Comment: How do you deduce that array element is not properly `free`d? `free` releases the memory but does not set the freed pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: I want to delete what i 've previsously saved in struct . free() is not enough?

Comment: Expounding on Jongware's comment, how do you know that the "example still remains not empty"?  Once you free the memory, you cannot reliably check it in any way, so how do you arrive at that conclusion?  In most implementations, the data doesn't change if you free it, and accessing it may look like nothing has happened.

Comment: Try clearing the contents of the struct using `memset()` or something **before** freeing it.

Comment: You don't have to set the members to null. For example, you can set them to some meaningless value, such as repetition of `0xff` or `0xDEADBEEF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To free a memory does not mean to clear the memory. After freeing an extent of memory the pointer thet points to it becomes invalid. However the extent can still contain the previous data if it will not be required by other request of memory.

Nevertheless accessing such an extent in general results in undefined behaviour.